# Allowing outgoing connections to a particular IP with ufw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ufw, cloudflare

**I have disabled outgoing connections as a whole with UFW seeing that I didn't want to take chances with my vBulletin forum exposing my server's IP address to attackers** (I use CloudFlare).

As I've done this, I've noticed I am unable to query one particular IP address which is called internally through code. **Now my question is, how can I allow only this specific IP (let's say 255.255.255.255) address to make outgoing connections?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple fix! Here's to anyone wondering how this can be done:

**1) Open `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and insert this rule above `COMMIT` on the last line**

```
-A ufw-before-output -m owner --uid-owner {user} -p {protocol} --dport {port} -d {ip} -j ACCEPT
```

Fill in the values for each as so:

`{user}` - user you want to allow this (www-data)

`{protocol}` - udp or tcp

`{port}` - on what port you want to allow it

`{ip}` - IP Address you want to allow.

*An example:*

```
# server
-A ufw-before-output -m owner --uid-owner www-data -p udp --dport 6666 -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT # gameserver
-A ufw-before-output -m owner --uid-owner www-data -p tcp --dport 3306 -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT # mysql

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

**2) Restart ufw `service ufw restart`**

Should all correctly work after! Ensure you don't put two ports in one like like "-dport 6666,5555" - it usually errors!

Answer (score 8):

I successfully allowed outgoing traffic to a specific ip on a specific port with the following command :

```
ufw allow out from any to <the.target.ip> port <port_number>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ufw allow out to <ip_adress> port <number of port>
sudo ufw allow out to 192.168.x.x port 22
sudo ufw reload
```

to allow outgoing ssh only for that IP